# How to open big EPUB files?

Tags: files, android-10, ebook-reader, google-play-books, reading

Just found out that Play Books has a limit of 100MB for each .EPUB file one wants to upload.

[image]

Are there alternative eReaders for Android that would allow to upload/read bigger .EPUB files?

This one has around 400MB.

I am wondering how should one open these files?

Comment: Have you tried [Perfect! Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rookiestudio.perfectviewer)?

Comment: Check out moon + reader pro.

Comment: eReader prestigio, but ideally chrome must add support for epub spec, it is part of W3C after all.